# Can I use VS2010 to generate a bunch of code and stuff it in a file as a pre-build step?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a bunch of those [assembly:] attributes to generate.. I need one in the assemblyInfo.cs file for each class in a certain directory of my project. The trouble is there's going to be hundreds of these classes eventually. I need to do this automatically. Thankfully, these attributes differ only by the class name, so I could easily generate them with code.

I don't think you can add these attributes at run-time so I need to do it in compile time.

Is there a feature in VS-2010 that allows me to generate a block of [assembly:] attributes and stuff them in the assemblyinfo.cs file before the project compiles?

Answer (score 2):

Would something like [T4 Templating Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) help?

Comment: This looks helpful. I'm going to try it out later.

Comment: T4 is the perfect answer to this.